# PhantomJS page.open() body executed multiple times for single page GWT web app

Tags: gwt, phantomjs

We would like to test a GWT single page web app using PhantomJS.

1. we load the page
2. fill in the login input fields
3. click on login
4. within a timeout, query elements on the page and print to the console
5. exit after 10s

Problem is that step 3. causes the entire body to be executed multiple times, meaning that the console.log statements within the body of our page.open() function print multiple times.

Anyone know what the problem is? How do we get the body to execute only once?

Here is the code that produces this behaviour:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.open("http://gwt-web-app.com#bookmark", function (status) {

    page.evaluate(function () {
        console.log('start login');
        document.querySelector('input#username').value = 'user';
        document.querySelector('input#password').value = 'pass';
        document.querySelector('button').click();   // causes body to be executed multiple times
        console.log('end login');
    });

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            console.log('start element query');
            // query elements, and print using console.log
            console.log('end element query')
        });
    }, 4000);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('exit');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);

});
```

The output is as follows (after running `phantomjs test_app.js`):

```
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
start element query
end element query
start login
end login
exit
```

Comment: Are you certain that it's not performing a redirect after you POST the login credentials? I had a similar scenario and the problem was caused by attempting to execute the "login" action even after the login elements were no longer there. Could you refactor to move the `open` callback into `page.onLoadFinished`? and then within *that* function, sniff for the login elements before attempting to use them?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it out next time we take a look at using PhantomJS.